# Spark SQL Column Manipulation

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset which has below Below Cols .

```
df.show();

+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col1  |  Col2   | Expend1 | Expend2 | Expend3 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Value1 | Cvalue1 |     123 |    2254 |      22 |
| Value1 | Cvalue2 |     124 |    2255 |      23 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want that to be changed to this below format using some joins or cube or any Operations.

1.

```
    +--------+---------+------+
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 |  123 |
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 | 2254 |
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 |   22 |
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 |  124 |
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 | 2255 |
    | Value1 | Cvalue1 |   23 |
    +--------+---------+------+
```

or Better if this format

2.

```
+--------+---------+---------+------+
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend1 |  123 |
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend2 | 2254 |
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend3 |   22 |
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend1 |  124 |
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend2 | 2255 |
| Value1 | Cvalue1 | Expend3 |   23 |
+--------+---------+---------+------+
```

Can I be able to achieve this above two Possible format. If In case of #1 , can I get the Column name of Last value , whether it is Expend1 or Expend 2 or Expend3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions `map` and then `explode` can be used:

```
val data = List(
  ("Value1", "Cvalue1", 123, 2254, 22),
  ("Value1", "Cvalue2", 124, 2255, 23)
)
val df = data.toDF("Col1", "Col2", "Expend1", "Expend2", "Expend3")

// action 
val unpivotedColumns = List("Expend1", "Expend2", "Expend3")
val columnMapping = unpivotedColumns.foldLeft(new ArrayBuffer[Column]())((acc, current) => {
  acc += lit(current)
  acc += col(current)
})
val mapped = df.select($"Col1", $"Col2", map(columnMapping: _*).alias("result"))
val result = mapped.select($"Col1", $"Col2", explode($"result"))
result.show(false)
```

Result is:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|Col1  |Col2   |key    |value|
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend1|123  |
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend2|2254 |
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend3|22   |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend1|124  |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend2|2255 |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend3|23   |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `array` for three columns and `explode` it

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("Expand", explode(array("Expand1", "Expand2", "Expand3")))
  .drop("Expand1", "Expand2", "Expand3")
```

To keep the column value you can do as below

```
  data.withColumn("Expand1", concat_ws(":", lit("Expand1"), $"Expand1"))
      .withColumn("Expand2", concat_ws(":", lit("Expand2") , $"Expand2"))
      .withColumn("Expand3", concat_ws(":", lit("Expand3") , $"Expand3"))
      .withColumn("Expand", explode(array("Expand1", "Expand2", "Expand3")))
      .drop("Expand1", "Expand2", "Expand3")
      .withColumn("ExpandColumn", split($"Expand", ":")(0))
      .withColumn("Expand", split($"Expand", ":")(1))
      .drop("Expand1", "Expand2", "Expand3")
    .show(false)
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: That works, Thanks Shanakar, But can I get to know the Name of Element of Expand Column for a particular row whether it is Expend1 or Expend2 or Expend3

Comment: You can use stack function to get the column name as well or append the column name with it and split later

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Hive function [`stack`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-stack(values)):

```
df.selectExpr("col1", 
              "col2", 
               "stack(3 , 'Expend1' , Expend1, 
                          'Expend2' , Expend2, 
                          'Expend3' , Expend3) 
                as (Expend, Value) "
              ).show(false)
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|col1  |col2   |Expend |Value|
+------+-------+-------+-----+
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend1|123  |
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend2|2254 |
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend3|22   |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend1|124  |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend2|2255 |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend3|23   |
+------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `udf` function you can achieve you *2nd required dataframe*.

```
val columns = df.select("Expend1","Expend2","Expend3").columns
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def arrayStructUdf = udf((columnNames: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], columnValues: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => columnNames.zip(columnValues).map(x => (x._1, x._2)).toArray)
```

Then just call the `udf` function, `drop` the three extra columns and then `explode` the new formed column and finally `select` the desired columns

```
df.withColumn("new", arrayStructUdf(array(columns.map(x => lit(x)): _*), array(columns.map(col): _*)))
    .drop("Expend1","Expend2","Expend3")
    .withColumn("new", explode(col("new")))
    .select("Col1","Col2", "new.*")
```

You should have the *2nd required dataframe*

```
+------+-------+-------+----+
|Col1  |Col2   |_1     |_2  |
+------+-------+-------+----+
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend1|123 |
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend2|2254|
|Value1|Cvalue1|Expend3|22  |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend1|124 |
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend2|2255|
|Value1|Cvalue2|Expend3|23  |
+------+-------+-------+----+
```