# joined based on the column value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v
how to do various joins depend on the value of column

Sample data

```
val data = List(
  ("20", "score", "school",  14 ,12),
  ("21", "score", "school",  13 , 13),
  ("22", "rate", "school",  11 ,14)
 )
val df = data.toDF("id", "code", "entity", "value1","value2")

+---+-----+------+------+------+
| id| code|entity|value1|value2|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
| 20|score|school|    14|    12|
| 21|score|school|    13|    13|
| 22| rate|school|    11|    14|
| 21| rate|school|    13|    12|
```

based the "code" column value i need to do join with various other tables

```
val rateDs = // val data1= List(
  ("22", 11 ,A),
  ("22", 14 ,B),
  ("20", 13 ,C),
  ("21", 12 ,C),
  ("21", 13 ,D)
)
```

val df = data1.toDF("id", "map_code","map_val")

```
val scoreDs = // scoreTable
```

if the "code" column value is "rate" i need to join with rateDs
if the "code" column value is "score" i need to join with scoreDs

how to handle these kind of things in spark ? any optimum way to achieve this?

**Expected result for "rate" fields**

```
+---+-----+------+------+------+
| id| code|entity|value1|value2|
+---+-----+------+------+------+
| 22| rate|school|     A|    B |
| 21| rate|school|     D|    C |
```

Comment: You can filter out in to two dataframes, join with other and union them again

Comment: @koiralo thanks , it is possible to do using "when" clause ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply join twice, for example

```
val data = List(
  ("20", "score", "school",  14 , 12),
  ("21", "score", "school",  13 , 13),
  ("22", "rate", "school",  11 , 14),
  ("21", "rate", "school",  13 , 12)    
 )
val df = data.toDF("id", "code", "entity", "value1","value2")

val data1 = List(
  ("22", 11 ,"A"),
  ("22", 14 ,"B"),
  ("20", 13 ,"C"),
  ("21", 12 ,"C"),
  ("21", 13 ,"D")
)
val rateDF = data1.toDF("id", "map_code","map_val")

df.as("a")
  .join(rateDF.as("b"),
       col("a.code") === lit("rate") 
        && col("a.id") === col("b.id") 
        && col("a.value1") === col("b.map_code"), "inner")
  .join(rateDF.as("c"),
       col("a.code") === lit("rate") 
        && col("a.id") === col("c.id") 
        && col("a.value2") === col("c.map_code"), "inner")
  .select(col("a.id"), col("a.code"), col("a.entity"), col("b.map_val").as("value1"), col("c.map_val").as("value2"))
  .show(false)

+---+----+------+------+------+
|id |code|entity|value1|value2|
+---+----+------+------+------+
|22 |rate|school|A     |B     |
|21 |rate|school|D     |C     |
+---+----+------+------+------+
```

Well, this looks a bit dirty, but I have no idea for the multiple columns...

Comment: thanks , it is possible to do using "when" clause ? this joins , i guess , would be performance hit.

Comment: That is not recommended when you join the tables.

Comment: what is being done here  coalesce("b.value1", "c.value1") ??

Comment: When `code = rate`, b.value1 will not be null, c.value1 will be null and when `code = score`, it will be reversed. So, coalesce collect those two results as a column but it is up to you, that is just an example.

Comment: after joining based on   col("a.id") === col("b.id"), "left")  condition , I need to loop up multiple column values i.e. "value_1" & "value_2" from "df" in "rateDs" ....how can that be handled ?

Comment: You can add more condition by adding `&&`. For example when you need to join entity column too, then `col("a.code") === lit("rate") && col("a.id") === col("b.id") && col("a.entity") === col("b.entity"), "left"`.

Comment: updated the question , can you check once , included sample rateDs  data  and Expected result for "rate"

Comment: thanks a lot , i have another use case like this , any advice please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137437/doing-multiple-column-value-look-up-after-joining-with-lookup-dataset